# GET/POST without browser history

Tags: php, browser-history, html5-history

I have a PHP shift scheduling app where the flow is: Welcome page > List of schedules page > Actual schedule page

On the Actual schedule page users can do things (like add a shift, remove a shift, request off a shift) that all post back to the same Actual schedule page. What I want is when they click on the various "things", the "things" are not added to the browser history.  So, if they click the browser's back button, they just go to the List of schedules page.

The issue I'm running into is you can add shift A, then add shift B, then click back and you're trying to add shift A again.

How is this typically avoided? What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to use AJAX form posts?

Comment: Currently, I'm not using forms for most things.  They're URL links formatted like page.php?week=1130&do=function

Comment: AJAX forms + manipulating browser history. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: If I understand you correctly: posting data to a server that will be added to a database, using GET requests is very dangerous, and I recommend changing how you do this. When you get it so that it uses GET/POST requests responsibly, AJAX requests.

Comment: This is typically avoided by using a system to manage the user's interaction using cookies, a session, post variables, and get variables (though typically get variables are disguised by url rewrites). Honestly, it's worth it learn a framework like Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post/Redirect/Get:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Another (old style) option is:
`$_POST` the data to a file the users do not go to, such as post_processing.php.
In that script, handle the processing of their requests, make changes as necessary, then header redirect back to the schedules page.

Obviously correctly handle anyone *trying* to access that file directly etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just return a `302` redirect from the POST handler to the page instead of rendering it.